# Cassandra restore into another server

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is it possible in Cassandra to restore from server A to server B?
If yes what is the correct way to do?I tried with below link but some query are failing.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_noderestart_t.html

Comment: Could you be more specific? How many nodes do you have in the cluster, multiple, only one? What errors are you getting when following the procedure?

Comment: I have only one node.

Comment: I have only one node. the error is when I use where clause in Cassandra query.Though I have data in the Cassandra still query return nothing, but the same query run in server A.

Comment: could you be more specific on where sever A and server B are located and what type of gossip are you using and some other critical information?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to below link for snapshot restore to copy data from one cluster to another.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupSnapshotRestore.html

You mentioned that you have two clusters with single node - query runs in A and does not on 2nd server. Depending on the query, data model and node's hardware/capacity, it may or may not be able to serve the query.

Try increasing cql query timeout 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlshrc.html

[connection]
request_timeout = 60

I would encourage you to go through Cassandra basics to understand how to build data model based on your query.